pelican-yaml-metadata doesn't parse markdown
I'm using pelican-yaml-metadata plugin in my Pelican website. From the documentation it should be possible to add markdown in yaml header:
---
title: Some title
author: Some person
tags:
  - tag 1
  - tag 2
date: 2014-12-25 00:00
summary: The article summary will be __parsed__ as markdown
---

This is some article text.

I added the plugin in the config file:
PLUGINS = [
    'yaml_metadata'
]

And I wrote an article:
---
title: My Article
template: project
challenge:
  text: Here is a challenge paragraph. It __should__ accept the markdown, including / new lines.
---

And this is article's description.

In my template I use it like this:
<div class="project-page--section project-page--challenge">
  <div class="project-page--section--text brown">
    <h2><img class="icon" src="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ THEME_STATIC_DIR }}/images/icons/challenge.svg" aria-hidden="true">CHALLENGE</h2>
      {{ article.challenge.text }}
  </div>
</div>

And what I achieve is:
Here is a challenge paragraph. It __should__ accept the markdown, including / new lines. 

The markdown in the challenge text is not parsed, the text is displayed unchanged. What am I missing?
